# Удаление фото со страницы

Tags: javascript, vue.js, изображения

я загружаю фото на страницу (input),при загрузки фото рядом появляется buttom(крестик) при клике на который фотка должна удаляться,как такое можно реализовать?

```
 [![<template>
                      <h2>Фотографии</h2>
                    </span><br>
                    <!-- Блок фоток-->
                    <div id="app" class="img-load">
                      <div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index" class="item-image">
                        <div class="img-container">
                          <img :src="item.url" alt="" v-if="item.url" @click="overallPopUp(index)" />
                          <img src="../assets/03.expert.inspection.photo.png" alt="" v-else/>
                          <img class="popUp" v-if="item.showPop" :src="item.url" v-click-outside="outOverallClick">
                          <v-btn class="btn-out" v-if="item.url" icon color="grey" small>
                            <v-icon color="black">clear</v-icon>
                          </v-btn>
                          <label class="loadfile" :class="{hide: item.url}">
                            <input class="inputfile" type="file" @change="overallFileSelected(index,'vin')">
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
    </template>
    <script>

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          items: \[
            {leftFront: "", url: "", showPop: false}, {leftBack: "", url: "", showPop: false}, {rightFront: "", url: "", showPop: false},
          \],
          selected: null,
          selectedFile: null,
          message: '',
          url: null,
          current: 0
        };
      },
      methods: {
          onFileSelected(event) {
            this.selectedFile = event.target.files\[0\];
            this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.selectedFile);
          },
          overallFileSelected(i, str) {
            this.items\[i\]\[str\] = event.target.files\[0\];
            this.items\[i\].url = URL.createObjectURL(this.items\[i\]\[str\]);
          },
          overallPopUp(i) {
            this.items\[i\].showPop = true;
          },
          outOverallClick() {
            for(let elem of this.items) {
              elem.showPop = false;
            }
          },
        },
        onUpload() {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append(this.selectedFile.name, this.selectedFile);
          formData.append('name', 'files');
          this.$store.dispatch('loadFile', formData);
        },
      },
      directives: {
        ClickOutside
      },
    };
    </script>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопке ставите `click` и вызываете remove с переданным `item.url`

```
<v-btn class="btn-out" v-if="item.url" icon color="grey" small @click="remove(item.url)">
  <v-icon color="black">clear</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Дальше в methods добавляете:

```
remove (url) {
  // исключает не нужный элемент
  this.items = this.items.filter(i => i.url !== url)
}
```